# What is Authorization callback URL? Android

Tags: android, eclipse, oauth-2.0, imgur, callbackurl

I need to use Imgur to upload images online using android eclipse. i created an account and was trying to register my application to get the client id and client secret. i reached here https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/addclient

I entered my Application Name as : com.nyp.assignment (is this just a name to it or we need to follow our package name? pls advise as well)

when i get to the callback url , i have no idea what to write for it. i've refered to here at https://api.imgur.com/oauth2 but still dont get it.

can someone list an example of a callback URL for Android? (Eclipse)

Comment: did u ever figure this out? im trying to upload images to an album on my account via android